# The abelian group G is n-divisible if (n,|G|)=1

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Consider the abelian group G. If n be a integer number such that (n,|G|)=1 ,Then G is n-divisible.why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need $G$ to be abelian to derive this.

Take any element $g ∈ G$.
Let $m = \operatorname{ord} g$.
Then $〈g〉 \cong ℤ/mℤ$ by $g ↦ 1$.
Now $m$ has to divide $|G|$, so $(n,m) = 1$ as well.
Therefore there is an $k ∈ ℤ$ such that $\overline{k}\overline{n} = 1$ in $ℤ/mℤ$.
Using the isomorphism from above what can you conlude about $g^k$ in $G$?